# Stripe Payment Gateway with 3D secure in asp.net without web hook

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

Can anyone help me with providing me demo of stripe payment gateway with 3d secure authentication in asp.net for v3 of stripe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this for step by step integration with 3D Secure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391324/how-to-integrate-stripe-payment-step-by-step-using-custom-form-in-asp-net-mvc/65391325#65391325